# The effct of hide of jquery ui can not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I chose jQuery UI in my project. I had defined two dialogs(dialogDIV and dlgTrn). Both show and hide of dialogDIV works fine, and show of dlgTrn works fine also.

But hide of dlgTrn works fail. When closing it, it has no explode effect.

Here is my js code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#dialogDIV").dialog({
  autoOpen:false,
  height:500,
  width:800,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
       },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
       }
  });

  $("#dlgTrn").dialog({
  autoOpen:false,
  height:250,
  width:400,
  show: {
      effect:"blind",
      duration:1000
       },     
  hide: {
      effect:"explode",
      duration:1000
      }
  });

  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({


   });
 });
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="dialogDIV" class="DIV">
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <div id="tabs" class="div2">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs1" style="font-size:10px">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs2" style="font-size:10px">b</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs1" style="height:70%;"></div>
    <div id="tabs2" style="height:70%;"></div>
 </div>  
</div>
 <div id="dlgTrn" title="stTrn"></div>
```

It is very strange. Who can help me ?

Comment: I do not see what opens or launches your dialogs.

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bwnhj528/1/

Comment: @Twisty, because  the area of height:250, and width:400, is too small. And the hide effect is not clear. When I chang height:1000 and width:1000, wow it has very clear effect. Thankyou !!